# JQuery change theme

Tags: jquery, css

I am almost there, created a button to change the CSS of my page with a button that says "Change Theme". I want the user to be able to change back and forth between 2 'themes'. Currently, the button works once and changes the theme but I can't get it to change back. I've tried to use the .toggle action but must not be calling it correctly because it just makes my page change immediately and takes away the button. Suggestions of where to add it in?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#themeButton').click(function(){
        $('#mcheader1').hide();
        $('#mcheader2').show();
        $('body').css('background-color', '#edd2fb');
        $('#focalimages').css('background-color','#540080');
        $('#focalimages').css('border-color', '#fce3f0');
        $('#container').css('border-color','#002aa7');
        $('#container').css('background-color','#fce3f0');
        $('#someID').css('border-color', '#002aa7');
        $('#someID').css('color', '#002aa7');
        $('ul').css('border-color', '#e70050');
      });
   });
```

Comment: Where in the code are you defining the other themes? I can see just a single one.

Comment: FYI a much easier way to achieve this is to put a class on the `body` which can be toggled in JS, and base the CSS of child elements off that class.

Comment: the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) you were looking for is now deprecated and has been removed from jQuery

Comment: ...but `.toggleClass()` still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply undo style changes like that--which is why CSS was invented. Use a class on the body (or some other common ancestor element), like Rory said, and toggle it all with one line.

```
body.otherTheme #mcheader1 {display: none;}
body.otherTheme #mcheader2 {display: block;}
body.otherTheme {background-color: #edd2fb;}
... 

$('#themeButton').click(function(){
    $(body).toggleClass('otherTheme');
});
```